# dbcontext scaffold --ouput-dir not working as expected in Linux

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I run this:

```
❯ dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'Server=localhost,1433;Database=Pub;User ID=sa;Password=Banana100;Trusted_Connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Models
Build started...
Build succeeded.
To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
```

**But nothing is created in my Models and** **I'm not even getting any errors**.
I tried with another proyects and is not working.
[image]

I have my nugget packages.
[image]

And dotnet ef is working fine.

[image]

*I'd really appreciate some help, I really want to use netcore in linux.*

Comment: so have you tried as error suggested, move hardcoded connection string to settings/configurations?

Comment: @LeiYang is not an error is a sugestion message to protect sensitive information in the connection string, like env variables, sadly it doesn't work :(

Comment: do you have sqlserver installed on linux, any commandline(e.g. sqlcmd) to prove it running?

Comment: @LeiYang Thank you for your kindness <3, don't worry I made it work, It was something in the string that I added and only works on Windows apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now use linux with dotnet.

Removing **Trusted_Connection=true;** did the trick

So this is the right command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'Server=localhost,1433;Database=Pub;User ID=sa;Password=Banana100;TrustServerCertificate=true;' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Models
```

**Beer** and **Brand** where created in the models, from my db.

[image]

Comment: from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15), this option seems need some network checking(AD), so it may be because you didn't wait enough time before the check fails. do you see the command exit or not?

Comment: @LeiYang I didn't exit, but in that part I'm reading that Trusted_Connection can be used if I'm using a DSN(Data Source Name). I'm using mssql with docker and not sure how to use a DSN with docker, and I won't  search it 'cause I'm sure is a huge pain to do it.
So I was using the default user of the docker "sa" and a passwd that mssql thinks is decent. Thank you for sharing now I understand why my connection was failing but without an error msg, It's a nice bug to report to microsoft, 'cause they haven't add an error for this kind of sitations on linux.

Comment: if it doesn't exit. please wait for at leat 5 minutes next try, because it should timeout. of course this can be a bug.